# How to clear Cache\session data while performing regression test using Coded UI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I am using Coded UI Keyword driven framework on VS2010 to run my regression test suite for a web application. Initially i recorded all the actions and created different test methods for each page and then made them keyword driven.

The problem i face is that on homepage there is pop up message that is displayed if the session or cache in browser has any last unsaved information about the user.

I am using a workaround/alternative

1. Clear cache before test run is started manually on each of test agents.
2. Closing the browser window each time single iteration is complete.

This approach i staking a lot of effort and some time when test fails the session data remains which leads to failure of all subsequent test case failure. Any programmatic approach\advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Rather than manually clearing the cache, you could record steps with Coded UI to clear the cache and add them to the start of the test.

Comment: That can be done. But this might not be the best way to tackle my problem. I am using searchconfiguration.alwayssearch in uimap.cs to start fresh test everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the cache in TestInitialize, so that as soon as any test starts, the first step is to clear the cache then proceed with the testing.

```
    #region Additional test attributes


    //Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test 
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
    // First launch your browser...
        this.UIMap.LaunchBrowserParams.Url = Config.WebServer;
        this.UIMap.LaunchBrowser();
    // This will clear your cache and cookies
        BrowserWindow.ClearCache();
        BrowserWindow.ClearCookies();
    }

    //Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
    [TestCleanup()]
    public void MyTestCleanup()
    {
    // Since you're concerned about failed tests not clearing cache at the end
    // I wouldn't bother with clearing the cache at the MyTestCleanup step.
        this.UIMap.CloseBrowser();

    }

    #endregion
```

EDITED: I edited the TestInitialize to launch the browser first. The browser has to be open before ClearCache and ClearCookies will do anything.